# How do I merge (or dynamically build and combine) lambda expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, merge, expression

I'm trying to dynamically combin lambda expressions. The code below will explain what I want. This is NOT a case of combining a=>b and b=>c to a=>c. Instead, I want to prevent code duplication by reusing conversion-expressions:

```
class User // convert from...
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}

class Person // convert to...
{
  public string Name
}

public class UserTransaction
{
  User FromUser {get;set;}
  User ToUser {get;set;}
  decimal Amount {get;set;}
}

public class PersonTransaction
{
  Person FromPerson {get;set;}
  Person ToPerson {get;set;}
  bool IsPositive;
}

Expression<Func<User, Person>> ToPerson = u => new Person {Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName};
Expression<Func<UserTransaction, PersonTransaction>> PersonTransaction = ut => new PersonTransaction {
  FromPerson = FromUser.Compile()(ut.FromUser), // Actually, I do not want to compile
  ToPerson = ToUser.Compile()(ut.FromUser), // (or double code)
  IsPositive = ut.Amount > 0
}
```

In the example above, I already have an expression to convert a user to a person. I do not want to duplicate this code or compile it. I've tried using stripping out the "compile"-calls by manually editing the expression tree. I did not succeed. Has anybody tried something similar and succeed?

Comment: You should look into a tool like AutoMapper that's built for doing conversions like this.

Comment: @Andrew I'm using AutoMapper in completely different parts of my application. It is used to automatically copy the content of objects to another. How does it convert expressions? (Some context: the expressions are used to eventually generate sql-queries.)

Comment: It does not deal with expressions, but it looks from your code like you're trying to convert `User` to `Person` and `UserTransaction` to `PersonTransaction`-- a mapping between two types

Comment: Well, I need an _expression_ that maps from UserTransaction to PersonTransaction. This expression is fed into existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some voodoo with `ExpressionVisitor` to *rewrite* your existing code to be fully inline; this:

- detects the invoke
- locates the Compile
- resolves the originating lambda
- swaps in all the parameter values directly
- rebuilds the expression tree accordingly

Have fun!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class User // convert from...
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Person // convert to...
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserTransaction
{
    public User FromUser { get; set; }
    public User ToUser { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class PersonTransaction
{
    public Person FromPerson { get; set; }
    public Person ToPerson { get; set; }
    public bool IsPositive { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<User, Person>> ToPerson = u => new Person { Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName };
        Expression<Func<UserTransaction, PersonTransaction>> PersonTransaction = ut => new PersonTransaction
        {
            FromPerson = ToPerson.Compile()(ut.FromUser), // Actually, I do not want to compile
            ToPerson = ToPerson.Compile()(ut.ToUser), // (or double code)
            IsPositive = ut.Amount > 0
        };
        var visitor = new RemoveCompilationsExpressionVisitor();


        var inlined = (Expression<Func<UserTransaction, PersonTransaction>>)visitor.Visit(PersonTransaction);
    }

    class ParameterSwapExpressionVisitor :ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> swaps;

        public ParameterSwapExpressionVisitor(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> swaps)
        {
            this.swaps = swaps;
        }
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            Expression result;
            return swaps.TryGetValue(node, out result) ? result : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
    class RemoveCompilationsExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression node)
        {
            var lambda = TryGetInnerLambda(node.Expression);
            if(lambda != null)
            {
                // this would be a partial solution, but we want to go further!
                // return Expression.Invoke(lambda, node.Arguments);

                var swaps = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
                for(int i = 0; i < lambda.Parameters.Count; i++)
                {
                    swaps.Add(lambda.Parameters[i], node.Arguments[i]);
                }
                var visitor = new ParameterSwapExpressionVisitor(swaps);
                return visitor.Visit(lambda.Body);
            }
            return base.VisitInvocation(node);
        }

        LambdaExpression TryGetInnerLambda(Expression node)
        {
            try
            {
                if(node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
                {
                    var mce = (MethodCallExpression)node;
                    var method = mce.Method;
                    if (method.Name == "Compile" && method.DeclaringType.IsGenericType && method.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                        == typeof(Expression<>))
                    {
                        object target;
                        if (TryGetLiteral(mce.Object, out target))
                        {
                            return (LambdaExpression)target;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /* best effort only */
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            return null;
        }

        static bool TryGetLiteral(Expression node, out object value)
        {
            value = null;
            if (node == null) return false;
            switch(node.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Constant:
                    value = ((ConstantExpression)node).Value;
                    return true;
                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                    var me = (MemberExpression)node;
                    object target;
                    if (TryGetLiteral(me.Expression, out target))
                    {
                        switch (me.Member.MemberType)
                        {
                            case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field:
                                value = ((FieldInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target);
                                return true;
                            case MemberTypes.Property:
                                value = ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target, null);
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind. I tried to do it in one pass, but using TWO expression visitors makes everything a lot easier!

Comment: @realbert indeed; note that for recursive compile/invoke chains, the parameter swap visitor could just inherit the invoke detection one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I'm now stuck getting the expression from my static conversion-class containing expression properties ( class X { static Expression<Func<P,Q>> Y {get{return p => new Q {};}} ), but I think I'll eventually succeed.